# Nestjs exiting on Container Start

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, containers, nestjs

My container is exiting immediately upon running.

I am using Nestjs and Postgres.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src

RUN apt update  && apt install python -y

COPY package*.json ./

RUN  npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build


FROM node:14.5.0-alpine

ENV PORT=3000

WORKDIR /src

COPY --from=build /src/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /src/dist ./dist

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "dist/src/main.js"]
```

Here is the console output:

[image: Output]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Seems like it is just compiling the files and not starting any server/daemon which keeps the container running.

Comment: What is the script to start project in package.json ? What is the output of `docker logs` ?

Comment: try `CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js"]` instead of `CMD [ "node", "dist/src/main.js"]`

Comment: @SuperSandro2000 Yes i think something like that

Comment: @Ted i am not using npm start, directly specified the CMD in dockerfile

Comment: @griFlo The output of my dist is structured like that, i have check the file structure in container using interactive shell

Comment: @Ted Docker logs just shows the exact same logs as given in the screenshot

Comment: Oh, you are using `node:14.5.0` as bulder but `node:14.5.0-alpine` for running container. I think they must be the same. Response if it work.

Comment: @Ted Tried but that dose not work, I am using the alpine version in the final image to decrease size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i solved it using Node version 13

I do not know whether the issue is in node 14 or if the Nest is not compatible with Node 14 yet.

For someone reading in future, here is the issue you can track :

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/5045